# Remember checkbox value

Tags: html, checkbox, jqtouch, local-storage, offline

Hi I would be so grateful if anyone could shed some light on this, Basically I have a iphone app built using jqtouch and phonegap which has a list of standard checkboxes and when they are selected a strikethrough effect will be applied, easy enough (kind of like a simple checklist) this is all dealt with on the client side and nothing will be getting sent anywhere.

However, when the user closes the app the checkboxes revert to their original sate i.e all unchecked and i would like them remain as the user left them. I guess local storage would be the way to do this, however, i have gave it a go and i am getting a bit confused.

Any help would be great, and thank you in advance.

kyle

Comment: You "gave it a go" and "are getting confused" contains zero useful information. We need useful information to help you with your problem. Please read: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Sorry if i didnt give enough information. Lets say for now all I have is a standard html form and nothing else with three checkboxes. when the user selects a box the boz will be ticked, what I wish is for when a user refreshes the page the state of the checkbox to remain the same i.e ticked and not revert back to its original state. This is it, no more, nothing less. Im guessing local storage would be the way, but im not sure thats why i was asking on here to see if anyone would be kind enough to help as i have been stuck for days now. Im sorry but I dont know what other info to give.

Comment: also i apologise in advance I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form')
    .delegate(':checkbox','change',function() {

        var $this = $(this);

        localStorage.setItem('checkbox' + $this.index('form :checkbox'),$this.attr('checked').toString());
    })
    .find(':checkbox')
    .each(function(index) {

        if(localStorage.getItem('checkbox' + index) === 'true') $(this).attr('checked',true);
    });
});
```

Took some time to write it correctly myself but I think it's worth it. The default state handling is up to you (like when a checkbox is already checked with HTML).